# In this simple code, why is the prompt value being ignored inside the function?

Tags: javascript

In the follow code:

I have tried passing whatThrow an argument as well. I don't seem to spot what is wrong.

```
var ranThrow = ["empty", "rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var ranNum = Math.random();
var postRanNum = (ranNum * 3) + 1;
var roundPostRanNum = Math.floor(postRanNum);
var compThrow = ranThrow[roundPostRanNum];
var whatThrow = prompt("Rock, Papper or Scissors?", "rock");

var rpsGame = function () {

  if (whatThrow === "rock" && compThrow === "rock")  {
      return "You tie!";
  }
  else if (whatThrow === "rock" && compThrow === "paper") {
      return "You lose!";
  }
  else if (whatThrow === "rock" && compThrow === "scissor") {
      return "You win!";
  }
  else {
      return "Error";
  }
};
rpsGame();

console.log("The computer threw" + " " + compThrow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value isn't ignored inside the function, it's the code that is calling the function that is ignoring what the function returns.

If you show the return value, you will see that the function uses the value:

```
console.log(rpsGame());
```

Comment: Ahh! Of course. It should have been more obvious to me. Thank you! I was under the impression that "return" would still log the string.